# MS Access Query Error with Aggregate and Group By Functions

Tags: ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

I just want to be enlightened with the issues I'm facing right now with a MS Access database. I can actually get results from a simple query statement but whenever I'm using Aggregate and/or Group By functions, I'm getting an error.

```
$rowno = 1;

$query = "SELECT COL1, MIN(COL2) AS time_in, MAX(COL2) AS time_out FROM TBL
        WHERE FORMAT(COL2, 'yyyy') = '2017' 
        GROUP BY COL1 
        ORDER BY COL2 DESC";

foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row){
    echo $rowno . ") " . $row['COL1'] . " - " . $row['time_in'] . " - " . $row['time_out'] . "<br/>";
    $rowno++;
}
```

And it gives me:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

My confusion is why the functions didn't work when actually the same query statement is working with another MS Access database? Is this something data or version problem? The statement is working when I removed the `MIN()`, `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` stuffs.

But anyway, here is a sample data that can be seen in the database I'm currently using:

```
COL1          COL2
 1      8/10/2017 4:53:31 PM
 1      8/10/2017 4:50:31 PM
 2      8/10/2017 4:43:31 PM
 2      8/10/2017 4:40:31 PM
 3      8/10/2017 4:33:31 PM
 3      8/10/2017 4:30:31 PM
```

Comment: That piece of programming is PHP, I guess. How are you connecting PHP with MS Access? And what exactly does this have to do with MySQL (since that's tagged)?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think it's nothing to do with the PHP. The problem is in the query statement itself. The connection is fine, I'm using  a PDO ODBC stuff. Okay, I'll remove mysql (I'm just confused).

Comment: Are you running your PHP on Windows, or are you using a 3rd party ODBC driver for Linux?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes to PHP on Windows sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ORDER BY statement is not an aggregate, while you're using a totals query. This should work:

```
$query = "SELECT COL1, MIN(COL2) AS time_in, MAX(COL2) AS time_out FROM TBL
        WHERE FORMAT(COL2, 'yyyy') = '2017' 
        GROUP BY COL1 
        ORDER BY MIN(COL2) DESC";
```

If your order by is not an aggregate, conflicts can occur. Assume you had the following table:

```
COL1          COL2
 1      8/10/2017 4:53:31 PM
 1      8/10/2017 4:50:31 PM
 2      8/10/2017 4:59:31 PM
 2      8/10/2017 4:40:31 PM
```

If you just order this by `COL2`, Access wouldn't know if it should put the aggregate row for `COL1: 1` before or after `COL1: 2`, since for `COL1:2`, `COL2` is both higher (in row 3) and lower (in row 4) than for `COL1: 1`

Comment: Yes it worked! But how? This is just my first time to use aggregate in ORDER BY because this is just my first time to encounter a problem like this. Is that because of date format? Maybe?

Comment: Nope, you're using a totals query, which means it aggregates results per row. If you're using `ORDER BY` in a totals query, you either have to use an aggregate (like min, sum, max, etc.) or use a column which is also in your `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: Oh. It's just weird because the same query statement is working fine with another Access database (without using aggregation in ORDER BY). But anyway, that's a lesson to remember. Thank you sir!

Comment: See my edited answer for why aggregates are required. In some cases, there won't be any conflicts, but as far as I know, it's always syntactically incorrect and should raise an error.

Comment: Oh I see. It's all clear to me now. I never thought of that (or rather learned) before. Thank you very much for that explanation  :)